# How to add a list at the end of a data frame row

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add four zeroes at the end of the data frame but i can't find a proper way to do it. This is the code: (The format that i want is [20 data points, 0, 0, 0, 0])

```
data_standard = np.array([0.782255,0.662182,0.150645,-0.896467,-0.876443,-0.808987,-1.699870,0.712200,0.171865,-0.762727,0.468775,0.051673,-1.015500,0.720511,0.654035,0.050556,-0.477682,1.407893,-0.019590,-0.817530])

holder_list = []

for i in range(5):
       noise_backup = (np.random.normal(0, 0.5) + data_standard)
       chart1 = plt.plot(data_standard, 'k-', label="HardCoded Data ONLY")
       chart2 = plt.plot(noise_backup, 'r-', label="HardCoded + RAW-Noise")
       Mean = (noise_backup/20)
       chart3 = plt.plot(Mean , 'b-', label="Mean of HardCoded + RAW-Noise")
       print(type(noise_backup))

       holder_list.append(noise_backup)

       print("This is the holder list: \n", holder_list)

       standard_deviation = np.std(data_standard)
       print("This is standard deviation: ", standard_deviation)

       leg = plt.legend(loc='lower right')
       print("These are HardCoded + RAW-Noise Data: \n", noise_backup)

       plt.show()

       df = pd.DataFrame(holder_list)

       print("This is df: \n", df)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe, and the output dataframe that you want in the question? I am struggling to understand what you mean :)

Comment: I want to put at the end of the dataframe the mean value for each chart in the iteration. Like the 20 data points and at the end of them mean value. Example : df = x1,x2.......xn,mean (in the same row)

Comment: Add at the end of your code `df["mean"] = df.mean(axis=0)`. It gets the mean of each row and adds it as a new column!